# Eclipse Oxygen on Linux not launching after reboot

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I wanted to transfer my installation of Eclipse Oxygen (3a April 2018) and data from Ubuntu 16 over to a fresh install of Ubuntu 18 on a new machine. I wasn't sure if it would cause trouble, but since Eclipse doesn't ever really seem to be "installed", I tried copying the following directories:

> ~/eclipse (installation directory)
>   ~/.eclipse
>   ~/.p2
>   ~/eclipse-workspaces

When I first copied everything over and tried to start Eclipse, it started up correctly and everything worked perfectly. I shut it down and rebooted my machine. Ever since then, when I try to launch it, I get the following error:

```
!SESSION Thu Jan 24 05:38:45 GMT 2019 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-01-24 05:38:45.057
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

The eclipse binary is in my PATH, so I've been trying to launch it by running the command `eclipse` from a terminal.

I've noticed something unusual with some of my configuration files. All of the line breaks have been replaced with literal "\n" characters. For example, the following `configuration/config.ini` file has this content:

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Thu Jan 24 05:21:14 GMT 2019
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=_home_rfynes_eclipse_eclipse
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.12.100.v20180210-1608.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
ds.delayed.keepInstances=true
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.2.1.v20180131-1435.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=file\:/home/rfynes/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.7.3.v20180330-0640
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.0.v20170516-1513.jar
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.p2.data.area=file\:/home/rfynes/.p2/\neclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
```

...but I had to manually replace all the literal "\n" with proper line breaks. Before I did that, that whole file content was on a single line. After I did that for the config.ini file, I got a different error in the log when I tried to start Eclipse:

```
!SESSION 2019-01-24 10:33:48.758 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
java.version=1.8.0_191
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.javascript.product --launcher.defaultAction
openFile --launcher.appendVmargs
-startup ../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.javascript.product --launcher.defaultAction
openFile --launcher.appendVmargs
-startup ../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-01-24 10:33:49.077
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Presumably there are other configuration files that have been mangled like this? Eclipse is writing these files, but why is it doing this? If this is the cause of the problem, then is this likely to be a problem with Eclipse or is it an issue with my system?

Comment: Please delete the `.log` file, try to restart Eclipse and add the content of the whole `.log` to your question. Show also the content of your `eclipse.ini`. Is there a reason to use an outdated Eclipse version?

Comment: That was the entire content of the log file. I noticed something unusual though. I've updated the question.

Comment: Do you have also `\n`s or relative paths in your `~/eclipse/eclipse.ini`?

Comment: There were also \n in the eclipse.ini after the reboot, but I manually fixed them up. I actually noticed that and fixed them before I posted the question, but I thought that was the only file affected. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the initial question.

Comment: If you only run Eclipse and do not upgrade Eclipse, `eclipse.ini` is only read but not written. So the `\n`s are not created by Eclipse. It seems your Eclipse installation is broken. Probably, also files in your `~/eclipse-workspaces/.metadata` are affected. You have to reinstall Eclipse, create a new workspace and import your project (which are hopefully not affected) into the new workspace (just deleting `~/eclipse-workspaces/.metadata` will not work, but you can rename the old workspace before creating a new one to keep the name).

Comment: @howlger I decided to do as you suggested and re-installed the latest Eclipse Photon from scratch. Although it's prob worth mentioning that my old eclipse installation on my Ubuntu 16 (old machine) is now broken too, suffering from the same issues (literal newlines in config files). It happened after I tried to launch it from the command line (I usually use an icon in the dock menu). So the installation must broken

Comment: That doesn't sound good. By the way, the current Eclipse version is 2018-12 (4.10), not Eclipse Photon (4.8).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187263/discussion-between-rtf-and-howlger).